# How to reslove the error "Incompatible types" while input from user using BufferedReader in java?

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {

    int x;
    InputStreamReader inputStreamReader = new InputStreamReader(System.in);
    BufferedReader bufferReader = new BufferedReader(inputStreamReader);
    x = bufferReader.readLine();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`bufferReader.readLine()` return `String`.
Change `int x` to `String x`

```
String x;
 ....
  your code
 ....
x = bufferReader.readLine();
Integer y= Integer.parseInt(x);
```

Comment: Thank you Khalid Shah, but i need output to integer.

Comment: @RanganRangan you can parse it into integer after ward. see my updated answer.

Comment: @RanganRangan welcome :) Accept it as answer / upvote it if  your problem is solved.

Answer (score 0):

If you are expecting to get the int value from the line, then you can parse the value using

`int x= Integer.valueOf( bufferReader.readLine());`

[Integer value of documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Integer.html#valueOf-java.lang.String-)

Comment: No problem : ) Glad if it helps